# Call the same code in every functions of a class

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a Network Manager class (singleton).

For every API call that the application has to make, a different function from this Network Manager is called.

I would like that every functions of this NM starts by displaying an Activity Indicator until the completion handler of each function is reached: showing the user that a request is being performed.

What would be the best way to do that?

I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) pod if that could help out.

Here is an example of one of my API call:

```
func loadSetting(for user: String, completionHandler: (UserSetting?) -> ()) {
    myActivityIndicator.start //a line I'd like to perform in every function of this class
    let parameters = ["UUID": user]

    _ = Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.google.com/users", parameters: parameters)
        .responseObject { (response: Response<UserSetting, NSError>) in
            if let userSetting = response.result.value {
                print("User Setting found remotely")
                completionHandler(userSetting)
            } else {
                print("Couldn't fetch remote User Setting")
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
            myActivityIndicator.stop //a line I'd like to perform in every function of this class
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: One solution is encapsulate all the requests in your NetworkManager in a function request, for example, and inside it you can handle the activity indicator.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, thanks Victor. But then I would have to pass a lot of parameters to dispatch each requests (request type, URL, params, files...), wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes but you can define it with default optional values as Alamofire do in fact.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I think I will go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try passing your activity indicator as an argument ?
So from the View controller where you're calling the loadSetting function, you pass in an activity indicator which you hold a reference to, and then inside your loadSetting function, you start/stop it there